# Array returning empty - Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

When i'm trying to receive all the data from a specific facebook page (that i have access, and garantee the access from my app) it return empty array.

But i use the same access_token in th graphic API explorer, i can see everything.

Any ideas why?!

Here's my code:

```
<?php
include (APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

class Fbpages_users extends Facebook {

public function Fbpages_users($pages) {

$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
$config = $ci->config->item('facebook');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '***********',
    'secret' => '**********',
));

parent::__construct($config);

for ($x=0; $x<count($pages); $x++) {

try {
$pageFeed = $this->api('/'.$pages[$x]['page_id'].'/feed?access_token='.$pages[$x]['access_token']);
$this->pagefeed = $pageFeed;
echo "<pre>";print_r($pageFeed); echo "</pre>";

for ($i=0;$i<count($pageFeed['data']);$i++) {

    for ($z=0;$z<count($pageFeed['data'][$i]['likes']['data']);$z++) {

    $query_fb_user_likes = $ci->db->query("
    SELECT user_id,id_fb_pages,type FROM fb_users
    where user_id like " . $pageFeed['data'][$i]['likes']['data'][$z]['id']
    . " AND id_fb_pages like " . $pages[$x]['id_fb_pages']
    . " AND type like 1
    ");
    $verifica_query_likes = $query_fb_user_likes->result_array();

        if ( (empty($verifica_query_likes)) AND ($pages[$x]['page_id'] != $pageFeed['data'][$i]['likes']['data'][$z]['id']) )
        {
        $likes = array(
            'id_fb_pages' => $pages[$x]['id_fb_pages'],
            'user_id' => $pageFeed['data'][$i]['likes']['data'][$z]['id'],
            'type' => '1'
        );
        $ci->db->insert('fb_users', $likes);
        }
    }

    for ($s=0;$s<count($pageFeed['data'][$i]['comments']['data']);$s++) {
    $query_fb_user_comments = $ci->db->query("
    SELECT user_id,id_fb_pages,type FROM fb_users
    where user_id like " . $pageFeed['data'][$i]['comments']['data'][$s]['from']['id']
    . " AND id_fb_pages like " . $pages[$x]['id_fb_pages']
    . " AND type like 2
    ");
    $verifica_query_comments = $query_fb_user_comments->result_array();

        if ( (empty($verifica_query_comments)) AND ($pages[$x]['page_id'] != $pageFeed['data'][$i]['comments']['data'][$s]['from']['id']) )
        {
        $comments = array(
            'id_fb_pages' => $pages[$x]['id_fb_pages'],
            'user_id' => $pageFeed['data'][$i]['comments']['data'][$s]['from']['id'],
            'type' => '2'
        );
        $ci->db->insert('fb_users', $comments);
        }
    }
}

$checked_pages_getusers = array(
    'page_id' => $pages[$x]['page_id'],
    'date_checked' => date ("Y-m-d H:i:s")
);
$ci->db->insert('checked_pages_getusers', $checked_pages_getusers);


} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
            $error = array(
                'logtype' => $pages[$x]['page_id'] . " - pages-users",
                'date' => date ("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'error' => "'" . $e . "'"
            );
            $ci->db->insert('error_log', $error);
}

}
//redirect('main/login');
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Can we see all the Facebook-related code you have?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert there

Comment: Can I see the structure of the `$pages` array (the one you pass to the `Fbpages_users` function)? Just `print_r` it. Can you also print the query: `'/'.$pages[$x]['page_id'].'/feed?access_token='.$pages[$x]['access_token']`. If it worked in the Graph API explorer, it has to be the same query here, but probably won't, I guess.